# Does Google Cloud Workflows work in europe-west2?

Tags: google-workflows

I'm trying to deploy a Google Cloud Workflow using terraform resource [google_workflows_workflow.](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/workflows_workflow)

Here is my code:

```
resource "google_workflows_workflow" "example" {
  project       = var.project_id
  name          = "workflow-example"
  region        = "europe-west2"
  description   = "My first workflow"
  service_account = var.service_account_email
  source_contents = <<-EOF
# etc...
EOF
```

It fails with:

> Error creating Workflow: googleapi: Error 403: Location europe-west2 is not found or access is unauthorized

Why is this? Is workflows not available in europe-west2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [closest Workflows region](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/locations) as of April 2021 is europe-west4.

Depending on your use case, region may not be as important for Workflows as it might be for other services. A workflow can call endpoints in any region, and in most cases latency is less important.